# Cargar un conjunto de imágenes y no su totalidad

Tags: ajax

Estaba haciendo unas pruebas pero no tengo claro como afrontarlo.

Tengo un contenedor con imágenes y lo que quiero es que solo se carguen aquellas que están visibles. Si el usuario hace scroll se carguen una nueva fila de imágenes. Al estilo de las tiendas de ropa de internet, para no cargar 200 imágenes si el usuario no las va a mirar.

¿Eso se hace mediante ajax verdad? De ser así, como se llama este hecho/acción para poder buscar info en internet.

Un saludo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te he entendido bien creo que te refieres a lo que se denomina "Lazy loading" combinado con un scroll infinito

Tienes varios plugins que te pueden servir (no necesariamente tienen que utilizar AJAX para cargar el contenido):

**Progressive image**

[Repositorio](https://github.com/craigbuckler/progressive-image.js)

[Demo](https://cdn.rawgit.com/craigbuckler/progressive-image.js/7f022aaf/demo.html)

**jQuery Lazy Load XT plugin**

[Repositorio](https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt)

[Demos](http://ressio.github.io/lazy-load-xt/demo/index.htm) > Contiene multitud de ejemplos (ajax incluido)

**[be]lazy.js**

[Web + demo](http://dinbror.dk/blazy/)

**Demo con jQuery (sin plugin propiamente dicho)**

http://jsfiddle.net/leolanese/N554G/

Answer (score 3):

Si eres nuevo trabajando con **Ajax** te recomendaría leer primero un poco sobre como funciona para luego poder implementarlo de la mejor manera posible según necesites.

Básicamente **ajax** funciona así:

[image: ajax]

Te dejo [este artículo](https://laredinfinita.wordpress.com/2014/04/22/esquema-de-ajax/) en español sobre como funciona.

Y si quieres aprender desde cero con ejemplos interactivos en línea, puedes revisar [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)